# Listing all directories except one

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a following directory structure

```
libs logs src etc .........
  |-- logs
  |-- src
  |-- inc
```

"logs" directory is everywhere inside. So I want to list all directories except "logs". What will be shell command for that.

Something like

```
#!/bin/bash
for dir in `find * -type d`; do
    if [[ ${dir} != "{logs}*" ]]; then
        echo ${dir}
    fi
done
```

but this does not seems to be working.

Regards,
Farrukh Arshad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than trying to process these things one at a time with checks, why don't you get *all* directories and just filter out the ones you don't want:

```
find * -type d | egrep -v '^logs/|/logs/'
```

The `grep` simply removes lines containing either `logs/` at the start or `/logs/` anywhere.

That's going to be a lot faster than individually checking every single directory one-by-one.

Comment: Ok. This is working, just wandering what is the difference between grep and egrep. Manual for both is same, but in above command egrep is working but grep is not working !!

grep does not seems to support |. Also -v means inverted selection, then whats the purpose of ^

Comment: `find` has the `-regex` test which eliminates the need to pipe output to `egrep` (which isn't safe for file names containing newlines anyway).

Comment: People with weird filenames like that deserve to be severely beaten :-)

Comment: @Farrukh, there are subtle differences between grep, egrep and fgrep, mostly wwith how they interpret the search string (regex variations for example).

Comment: grep usually for one search pattern egrep for multiple you can use | to find something or another or use + to find something and another

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the above comment you can use egrep and | to separate patterns or like below define it all in find

```
 find . -type d -print
.
./logs1
./test
./logs


$ find . -type d -not -name logs -not -name logs1  -print
.
./test
```